# Command to remove all white spaces in vim

Tags: vim

I want to be able to remove all the white spaces in my txt file using vim

```
update reg04_rpt_animreg set birthdate = '      2016-01-21       ' where animalid = '   TZN000192803889  ';
update reg04_rpt_animreg set birthdate = '      2015-07-05       ' where animalid = '   TZN000192803890  ';
update reg04_rpt_animreg set birthdate = '      2011-12-12       ' where animalid = '   TZN000192803891  ';
update reg04_rpt_animreg set birthdate = '      2013-05-05       ' where animalid = '   TZN000192803893  ';
update reg04_rpt_animreg set birthdate = '      2013-04-02       ' where animalid = '   TZN000192803894  ';
update reg04_rpt_animreg set birthdate = '      2015-05-16       ' where animalid = '   TZN000192803895  ';
```

I have used the following command with vim but havent gotten my expected output

```
:g/^\s*$/d
```

Comment: It would be easier if you showed us the desired output.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for the `s` command; `:g/<regexp>/d` deletes the whole line which matches `<regexp>`.

```
:%s/\s//g
```

This replaces all space-type characters (`\s`) globally (`g`).

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to trim spaces inside the single quotes only, this should work:

```
:%s/= '\zs\s*\(\S*\)\s*'/\1'/g
```